Proof of $K_0(z)=-\left(\log\frac{z}{2}+\gamma\right)I_0(z)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(z/2)^{2n}}{n!^2}H_n$
Let $I_{\nu}$ be the Bessel I function of order $\nu$ defined by
$$I_{\nu}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z/2)^{2n+\nu}}{n!\Gamma (n+\nu+1)}$$
and let $K_{0}$ be the Bessel K function of order $0$ defined by
$$K_0(z)=\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{\nu\to 0}\frac{I_{-\nu}(z)-I_{\nu}(z)}{\sin \nu\pi}.$$
I want to find a proof (references are sufficient) of
$$K_0(z)=-\left(\log\frac{z}{2}+\gamma\right)I_0(z)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(z/2)^{2n}}{n!^2}H_n$$
where $z\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $\gamma$ is Euler's constant and $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number, which actually appears as eq. 10.31.2 in the DLMF.
This formula is very important because it is a basis of the fastest known algorithm for computing $\gamma$.
What I tried
I noticed that to prove the formula in question, it is sufficient to prove two things, then the formula is trivial because of the formula relating harmonic numbers with the digamma function.
First:
$$K_0(z)=-\left[\frac{\partial I_{\nu}(z)}{\partial\nu}\right]_{\nu=0};$$
Second:
Interchanging the the $\nu$-derivative and the infinite series defining $I_{\nu}(z)$ is legitimate.
Regarding the first thing:
We have, by the deinition of the derivative
$$\begin{align}\left[\frac{\partial I_{\nu}(z)}{\partial\nu}\right]_{\nu=0}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left[\frac{I_{\nu+h}(z)-I_{\nu}(z)}{h}\right]_{\nu=0}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{I_h(z)-I_0(z)}{h}\end{align}$$
but that doesn't explain where the sine term comes from, etc.
Regarding the second thing: Proving that we could interchange the $z$-derivative and the infinite series defining $I_{\nu}(z)$ would be easy, as it is a power series uniformly convergent on compacts with respect to $z$. But proving that we can interchange the $\nu$-derivative and the infinite series defining $I_{\nu}(z)$ seems out of reach for me.

For your first claim, for non integer $\nu$, $K_\nu$ is defined by:
$$
K_\nu = \frac\pi2\frac{I_{-\nu}-I_\nu}{\sin(\pi \nu)}
$$
The idea is to extend by continuity at the integer values. Assuming $I_\nu$ is derivable with respect to $\nu$ at $0$, from l'Hôpital's rule:
$$
K_0 = -\left[\frac{\partial I_\nu}{\partial\nu}\right]_{\nu=0}
$$
The derivability of $I_\nu$ is a standard application of taking the derivative under the sum. Writing:
$$
I_\nu = \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n(\nu)\\
u_n(\nu) := \frac{(z/2)^{2n+\nu}}{n!\Gamma(n+1+\nu)}
$$
since $u_n$ is $\mathcal C^1$ on $(-1,+\infty)$, you just need to prove that the series $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\partial u_n(\nu)}{\partial\nu}$ converges uniformly in a neighbourhood of $0$. Starting the index at $2$ just makes things a bit easier. You can prove this by explicit computation:
$$
\frac{\partial u_n(\nu)}{\partial\nu} = (\ln(z/2)-\psi(n+\nu+1))u_n
$$
A slight technical issue is that the convergence is not uniform on the natural domain $(-1,+\infty)$. For your problem, it suffices to use $nu\in(-1,\nu_1)$ with $0<\nu_1$.
From there, you just need to prove that the sum converges normally. For $n\geq 2$, $-1<\nu<\nu_1$, you can bound by:
$$
\left|\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial\nu}\right|\leq \frac{(|z|/2)^{2n}e^{|\ln(|z|/2)|\nu_1}}{n!(n-1)!}(|\ln(z/2)|+H_{n-1}-\gamma)
$$
Here, I used $n\geq 2$ to use the fact that $\Gamma$ is positive, increasing on $(2,+\infty)$ and $\psi$ positive, increasing as well. The RHS converges by applying d'Alembert's criterion and using $H_n/H_{n-1}\to1$. Thus, $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\partial u_n(\nu)}{\partial\nu}$ converges normally on $(-1,\nu_1)$, so $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\partial u_n(\nu)}{\partial\nu}$ is $\mathcal C^1$ on $(-1,\nu_1)$. Adding the terms $n=0,1$, which are individually $\mathcal C^1$, you conclude that $I_\nu$ is $\mathcal C^1$ over $(-1,\nu_1)$. In particular, it is derivable at $0$.
As you can see, you need to bound $\nu$ in order to have uniform bound for the exponent when $|z|>2$. In fact, since the previous is true for arbitrarily large $\nu_1$, $I_\nu$ is $\mathcal C^1$ over $(-1,+\infty)$.
Hope this helps.
